# Alterar consulta MySQL para funcionar no SQL Server e Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, oracle

Alguém saberia me falar como essa consulta em MySQL ficaria em SQL Server e em Oracle?

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
    SUM(EVENTO = 7 AND RESULTADO = 0) AS QTD_RX_OK,
    SUM(EVENTO = 7 AND RESULTADO <> 0) AS QTD_RX_ERR,
    SUM(EVENTO = 5 AND RESULTADO = 0) AS QTD_TX_OK,
    SUM(EVENTO = 5 AND RESULTADO <> 0) AS QTD_TX_ERR,
    SUM(EVENTO = 8 AND RESULTADO = 0) AS QTD_ROUTING_OK,
    SUM(EVENTO = 8 AND RESULTADO <> 0) AS QTD_ROUTING_ERR,
    SUM(EVENTO = 1 AND RESULTADO = 0) AS QTD_SESSION_IN_OK,
    SUM(EVENTO = 1 AND RESULTADO <> 0) AS QTD_SESSION_IN_ERR,
    SUM(EVENTO = 2 AND RESULTADO = 0) AS QTD_SESSION_OUT_OK,
    SUM(EVENTO = 2 AND RESULTADO <> 0) AS QTD_SESSION_OUT_ERR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (EVENTO = 7 AND RESULTADO = 0) THEN TAMARQUIVO ELSE 0 END ) AS QTD_BYTES_RX_OK,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (EVENTO = 5 AND RESULTADO = 0) THEN TAMARQUIVO ELSE 0 END ) AS QTD_BYTES_TX_OK,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (EVENTO = 8 AND RESULTADO = 0) THEN TAMARQUIVO ELSE 0 END ) AS QTD_BYTES_ROUTING_OK,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN (EVENTO = 7 AND RESULTADO = 0) THEN TAMARQUIVO ELSE 0 END ) / SUM(EVENTO = 7 AND RESULTADO = 0)) AS QTD_MEDIA_RX_OK,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN (EVENTO = 5 AND RESULTADO = 0) THEN TAMARQUIVO ELSE 0 END ) / SUM(EVENTO = 5 AND RESULTADO = 0)) AS QTD_MEDIA_TX_OK,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN (EVENTO = 8 AND RESULTADO = 0) THEN TAMARQUIVO ELSE 0 END ) / SUM(EVENTO = 8 AND RESULTADO = 0)) AS QTD_MEDIA_ROUTING_OK
FROM TBLTRANSFERS 
WHERE DATAHORA BETWEEN '2017-03-14 09:40:02' AND '2017-03-14 09:50:02'
    AND (UPPER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NOMEARQUIVO, '\\\\', -1)) LIKE '/Users/teste/tmp/teste/data/app/Relatorio.pdf')
    AND (INSTANCE = 'appl02' AND USUARIO = 'teste');
```

**SQL SERVER**

Para a Criação do BD no SQL Server, segue o script:

```
CREATE TABLE TBLTRANSFERS
(
IDTRANSFER INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
DATAHORA DATETIME NOT NULL,
INSTANCE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '*',
USUARIO VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CONEXAO TEXT NULL,
DATAARQUIVO CHAR(8) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
EVENTO INT NOT NULL,
HORAARQUIVO CHAR(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
MAXTAMREG INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
MENSAGEM VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
NOMEARQUIVO VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PROCID INT NOT NULL,
REDE VARCHAR(16) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
RESULTADO INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
TAMARQUIVO DECIMAL(11,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
THREADID INT NOT NULL,
TIPOREC CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX DATAHORA
ON TBLTRANSFERS (DATAHORA);

CREATE INDEX DATAHORA_2
ON TBLTRANSFERS (DATAHORA, USUARIO);
```

Para inserção no SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TBLTRANSFERS
(DATAHORA, INSTANCE, USUARIO, CONEXAO, DATAARQUIVO, EVENTO, HORAARQUIVO, 
MAXTAMREG, MENSAGEM, NOMEARQUIVO, PROCID, REDE, RESULTADO, TAMARQUIVO, 
THREADID, TIPOREC)
VALUES
('2017-03-14 09:45:02', 'testeapp', 'teste',  'testando texto',
'', 2, '', 0, 'Fim de sessao de entrada', '/Users/teste/tmp/data/river/teste/Relatorio.pdf', 99098, 'teste', 0, 13074, 3740130, 'U');
```

**ORACLE**

Criação Oracle

```
CREATE TABLE TBLTRANSFERS
(
IDTRANSFER NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
DATAHORA TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
INSTANCE VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '*' NOT NULL,
USUARIO VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CONEXAO CLOB NULL,
DATAARQUIVO CHAR(8) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
EVENTO NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
HORAARQUIVO CHAR(6) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
MAXTAMREG NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
MENSAGEM VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
NOMEARQUIVO VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
PROCID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
REDE VARCHAR(16) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
RESULTADO NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
TAMARQUIVO DECIMAL(11,0) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
THREADID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
TIPOREC CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL
);

CREATE INDEX DATAHORA_TBLTRANSF
ON TBLTRANSFERS (DATAHORA);

CREATE INDEX DATAHORA_2_TBLTRANSF
ON TBLTRANSFERS (DATAHORA, USUARIO);

CREATE SEQUENCE TBLTRANSFERS_SEQ
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 100;
```

Inserção Oracle:

```
INSERT INTO TBLTRANSFERS(IDTRANSFER, DATAHORA, INSTANCE, USUARIO, CONEXAO, 
DATAARQUIVO, EVENTO, HORAARQUIVO, MAXTAMREG, MENSAGEM, NOMEARQUIVO, PROCID, 
REDE, RESULTADO, TAMARQUIVO, THREADID, TIPOREC)
VALUES
(TBLTRANSFERS_SEQ.NEXTVAL, to_date('2017-03-14 09:45:02', 'YYYY-MM-DD 
HH24:MI:SS'), 'testeapp', 'river2',  'teste de texto',
'', 2, '', 0, 'Fim de sessao de entrada', '/Users/teste/tmp/data/teste/caixaEntrada/Relatorio.pdf', 99098, 'teste', 0, 13074, 3740130, 'U');
```

Comment: Dê um exemplo do que tem na coluna `nomearquivo`

Comment: É o caminho... Ex: /Users/lucas/tmp/teste/data/appl01/user/outbox/Relatorio.pdf

Comment: Qual a diferença entre ele e a `String` que você está utilizando para buscar (do outro lado do `LIKE`?)

Comment: Não tem... Poderia ser só "Relatorio.pdf" depois do like, tanto faz... Eu preciso mudar essa query para funcionar no SQL Server e no Oracle... Pois essa funciona somente no MySQL

Comment: Você quer que funcione pros 3 com a mesma `query` ou uma pra cada uma?

Comment: Pode ser um para cada

Comment: No Oracle use to_date( '2017-03-14 09:40:02','yyyy-mm-dd hh24?mi:ss') para a data/hora e troque o  SUBSTRING_INDEX por um instr e susbtr

Comment: @Motta No caso do Oracle não precisa alterar mais nada?

Comment: se fosse possível você fornecer alguns scripts de criação e população para podermos testar.

Comment: @LuizSantos Acrescentei os scripts de criação e inserção, se conseguir me dar uma força, ficaria muito grato...